# Why am I getting this error with userDataPersistance example

Tags: bixby

GitHub was refreshed 3 days ago . I'm following the instructions and created my configs & secrets for both dev & prod... but I get this error as soon as changing the capsule id to mine and the capsule properties to "default"

the error is a missing "null.js" file which was not showing an error when using the example

Comment: Please refer to the latest answer posted here.  This issue has been resolved in the latest Github version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have confirmed this behavior when working through the sample and documentation.

Here's the problem, Bixby is throwing a compile error because it isn't accessing the cloud config setting until it's running.  So, it's looking for the file config and doesn't see the 'service' setting.  You can remove the compile error by adding this property to the config file.

```
config.default.service=restdb.js
```

or

```
config.default.service=airtable.js
```

If you've chosen one of those services, it isn't likely that you'll switch.  So, this should work as a solution to the issue you're having.

Comment: The definitely fixed the compile error, but I now getting a when the query runs

Comment: If you've configured the config and secret correctly, you should have a working capsule.  I've verified success following the instructions for AirTable as the storage service.    https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/blob/master/user-data-persistence/airtable.md

Comment: So is the "config" part of "configs and secrets" actually a one-line view into a config file? I did not understand that before.

Comment: Your solutions works great. I'm using it with airtable

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved.  Get the latest sample hosted on github [here](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/user-data-persistence)  Follow the instructions for saving data to your own restdb or airtable services.  No need to use the previous answer when you're on the latest version.